# Running React native application using expo application on android device

Tags: react-native, expo

I have set up a react native project using `create-reacte-native-app`.

**Problem**

I am trying to run the application on my android device using `expo` app but when i scan the `QR code` using expo app, i get an error

```
could not load expo://192.168.8.103:19000. Network response timed out.
```

Error log displays this error message

`Uncaught Error:Java.net.SocketTimedoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.8.103 (port 19000) from /192.168.8.105 (port 38682) after 10000ms`

**Question**

How can i fix this error and run my react native app on android device using expo app?

Answer (score 0):

Try to be on the same network (computer and phone)

and you can try to run it with `exp start`

Comment: its happened to me a few times...try to use on **Expo XDE** there are a few of option to run the app